# Two way sum table

Tags: r, dataframe, tapply

Here is some example data, `df`:

```
age_group class Value
   0-4      A     2
   0-4      A     1
   0-4      B     1
   5-9      A     2
   5-9      A     3
   5-9      B     1
   5-9      B     1
   9-14     A     1
```

I have been attempting to create a two way summary table -something like this:

```
   0-4 5-9 9-14
A   3   5   1
B   1   2   NA
```

I thought i had cracked it last night with:

```
tmp = with(df, tapply(Value), list(age_group, class), FUN=sum))
```

However when inspecting this table the numbers don't tie up with what i would expect.

Does anyone know what my `tmp`table actually represents? Also how would i get my desired result?

Thanks,
John

Comment: ? `aggregate()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family oder `xtabs(Value ~ class + age_group, data=df)`

Comment: Trying `tmp2 <- aggregate(as.numeric(as.character(S4.Data$Value)), list(S4.Data$Org.Name, S4.Data$Measure_Desc), sum)` gives me what i would like but not in my desired format, preferably would like a two value table. Very useful like though thanks - will bookmark. xtabs gives me a frequency table which is also in the three column format rather than the two way table one i am after. (just realised that my code above is giving me frequency rather than a sum)

Comment: `with(df, tapply(Value, list(class, age_group), FUN=sum))` works for me. Are you getting an error? What doesn't work?

Comment: Why are you doing `as.numeric(as.character(S4.Data$Value))`? Is it a `factor` currently? It might be best to post a few lines of your actual data as a `dput`....

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 `with(df, tapply(Value, list(class, age_group), FUN=sum))` is different from what i used : `tmp = with(df, tapply(Value), list(age_group, class), FUN=sum))`. The former produces a list of length 8, while the latter (at least for me anyway). Yes my data is a factor which is why i have to convert to char and then num.

Comment: @JDraper, What you've posted in your comment shouldn't even work....

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 this code? `with(df, tapply(Value), list(age_group, class), FUN=sum))` Also sorry i can't post the data for confidentiality reasons. If it helps Value is a factor (which gets converted to numeric), Org.Name is a factor and Measure_desc is a character.

Comment: @JDraper, yes. How can you do `tapply(Value)`?

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 my code when using `tapply` (which doesn't throw out an error): `with(S4.Data, tapply(as.numeric(as.character(Value)), list(Org.Name, Measure_Desc), FUN=sum)))`